# VS 2017 - UI Automation - Keyboard.Sendkeys("sometext") is throwing null exception in VS 2017 where as it works in VS2013 & VS2015

Tags: selenium

UI Automation - Keyboard.Sendkeys("sometext") is throwing null exception in VS 2017 where as it works in VS2013 & VS2015

I am trying a simple command in test method. Trying to enter some text with Keyboard.Sendkeys("Text");
It gives null exception. And error object is not set to instance of object. Thanks in advance for the help

VS 2017 Enterprise endition

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send text to the Open dialog you may try this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(path);
```

But I would like to remind you, to uplad a file to web page using WebDriver you should send file path to the .

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("fiePath")).SendKeys(path);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am trying to upload a document through browse button. upon click it open button, it opens browse desktop dialog. Here am using Keyborad.Sendkeys(""). This was working until we migrated to 2017.

Comment: To 'upload' a file you should send text to the input. It could be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. If Keyboard.Sendkeys("") work in VS 2017. I would be able to handle the Upload functionality. If i create a Codedui project, and have test method with only Keyboard.sendkeys(""). it goes to null exception. The other way i can use auto it. Since i was handling the desktop dialog textbox with sendkeys i wanted to continue with it..

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(path); Thanks a lot for the help. this worked for me.